# ArcGIS Server - writing error messages to jobs

Tags: arcgis-server, error, geoprocessing-service, arcgis-10.8

I'm trying to aid some of my other teams by improving the error handling when geoprocessing services are being called. In my code I'm handling errors however after publishing that code to the server 10.8. I cannot see any errors being written out under jobs\jobid URL of the REST API. Is there some specific standard I need to follow in order for messages to be written to ArcGIS Server REST API when looking at the status of a job?

Comment: Can I assume you mean you've put `arcpy.AddError("Foo")` in your Python script tool you've published, and you're not seeing that error? When you say jobs\jobID -- not sure what you're expecting. If indeed you're using AddError, this will get pushed into the messages of the execution (if you have the correct message level set) and the Server logs.

Comment: Thank you @KHibma the message level for the service is what the issue was. I just was not familiar with the setting!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geoprocessing Services have 4 level of messages that can be returned and viewed during execution. If this setting is **None**, no messages, not even Error messages are returned.

See the [service settings](https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/publish-services/windows/geoprocessing-service-settings-parameters.htm) help for a complete break down of the levels.